# magento unregister helper from uninstalled module

Tags: magento

recently I installed subcription extension in my Magento installation. but this module give headache to me, then i uninstall it. once it uninstalled then I try to login as customer at the frontend, after login there is an error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Customweb_Subscription_Helper_Data' not found in /home/optimallyorganic/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

how to disable this helper class `Mage_Customweb_Subscription_Helper_Data`?

Comment: Delete all the module files. Should be under app/code/community/Customweb or app/code/local/Customweb. Also delete the module file in app/etc/modules/Customweb_Subscription.xml. Then clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

In the backend panel go to `System -> Configuration -> Admin -> Advanced` 
and disable your module!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database, in core_resource table search in your case `"%Customweb%"`, delete the record, and your uninstalled extension will not bother you again.